# java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 57

Tags: android, eclipse, android-layout, android-studio, admob

A perfectly working application project has started giving this error in Android Studio. I have tried various things like changing the structure of Main.xml file, changing Google Play Services version, etc. but nothing has helped. This error show up in the display tab and I have tried using api 18 for the viewing. Also for some reason the fill rate of Interstitial Ads has gone down to 0 and it returns NO_FILL.

```
The following classes could not be instantiated:
- com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView (Open Class, Show Exception)
 Tip: Use View.isInEditMode() in your custom views to skip code or show sample data when shown in the IDE

java.lang.VerifyError: Expecting a stackmap frame at branch target 57
Exception Details:
  Location:
    com/google/android/gms/ads/AdView.onMeasure(II)V @20: ifnull
  Reason:
    Expected stackmap frame at this location.
  Bytecode:
    0000000: 033e 0336 042a 03b6 0015 3a05 2ab6 0014
    0000010: 3a06 1905 c600 2519 05b6 000b 1008 9f00
    0000020: 1b2a 1905 1b1c b600 1919 05b6 000a 3e19
    0000030: 05b6 0009 3604 a700 1f19 06c6 001a 2ab6
    0000040: 0016 3a07 1906 1907 b600 133e 1906 1907
    0000050: b600 1236 041d 2ab6 0018 b800 2a3e 1504
    0000060: 2ab6 0017 b800 2a36 042a 1d1b b800 0d15
    0000070: 041c b800 0db6 001a b1                 

at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructors0(Native Method)
at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredConstructors(Class.java:2532)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:2842)
at java.lang.Class.getConstructor(Class.java:1718)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.createNewInstance(ViewLoader.java:309)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.ViewLoader.loadView(ViewLoader.java:99)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.LayoutlibCallback.loadView(LayoutlibCallback.java:172)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.loadCustomView(BridgeInflater.java:207)
at android.view.BridgeInflater.createViewFromTag(BridgeInflater.java:132)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate_Original(LayoutInflater.java:802)
at android.view.LayoutInflater_Delegate.rInflate(LayoutInflater_Delegate.java:64)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:778)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:500)
at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:381)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.impl.RenderSessionImpl.inflate(RenderSessionImpl.java:400)
at com.android.layoutlib.bridge.Bridge.createSession(Bridge.java:329)
at com.android.ide.common.rendering.LayoutLibrary.createSession(LayoutLibrary.java:332)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:575)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService$3.compute(RenderService.java:564)
at com.intellij.openapi.application.impl.ApplicationImpl.runReadAction(ApplicationImpl.java:932)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.createRenderSession(RenderService.java:564)
at com.android.tools.idea.rendering.RenderService.render(RenderService.java:691)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.doRender(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:604)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.access$1900(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:80)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7$1.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:546)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl$2.run(ProgressManagerImpl.java:178)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.ProgressManager.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManager.java:209)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.executeProcessUnderProgress(ProgressManagerImpl.java:212)
at com.intellij.openapi.progress.impl.ProgressManagerImpl.runProcess(ProgressManagerImpl.java:171)
at org.jetbrains.android.uipreview.AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager$7.run(AndroidLayoutPreviewToolWindowManager.java:541)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:320)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.execute(MergingUpdateQueue.java:310)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue$2.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:254)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:269)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.flush(MergingUpdateQueue.java:227)
at com.intellij.util.ui.update.MergingUpdateQueue.run(MergingUpdateQueue.java:217)
at com.intellij.util.concurrency.QueueProcessor.runSafely(QueueProcessor.java:238)
at com.intellij.util.Alarm$Request$1.run(Alarm.java:327)
at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:262)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

**build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.0.89'
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:20.+'
    compile 'com.crashlytics.android:crashlytics:1.+'
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I can't mark this question I am posting the answer from the other [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24587991/android-studio-admob-the-following-classes-could-not-be-instantiated).

```
I had the same problem when trying to preview the custom view AdView. My
project is built using gradle via Intellij community edition (13.x) and 
I ended up changing the version of google play services from

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:5.+'

to

compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'

specifically, I changed the dependencies section of my gradle file to look
like this:

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:4.+'
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I had a same issue. and searched a lot but none answer help me.

I think this might be bug in google-play-service

Then I get new API from my friends computer(in his computer his api working perfectly so I just replaced that and it was working.)
[here is my friends api](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B_zjTpTtktM3UFU0VXdEa25kNGJSTUl4SjRDX2hHVUdBSjNv/edit?usp=sharing)

try this api this might helps you.

Comment: Though this is not an answer what I want but this is only answer that solve my problem. so you get +50 Mr. Crazy Proggrammer.

Answer (score 1):

With JDK 5 there was a new type checking introduced (see [JVM options](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html), UseSplitVerifier) but was disabled by default. As you define

```
targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
```

the bytecode you build will use this feature (see: [JVMS 4.10.1. Verification by Type Checking](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.10.1) and [4.7.4. The StackMapTable Attribute](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jvms/se7/html/jvms-4.html#jvms-4.7.4) ). To disable this feature you can pass the option `-XX:-UseSplitVerifier` to the java<strike>c</strike>.

Comment: I already use compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_7
    } in app's build.gradle from the start and it hasn't helped. https://gist.github.com/donniezazen/ead9fd8a2505eda11884

Comment: If you are not using any specific JDK 7 features try to use VERSION_1_5.

Comment: Gail posted the correct [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/25748196/3034693) 3 days ago. And I can't remove 1.7 compatibility because I am using String in a switch statement.